# Ассемблер, TASM заполнить видеопамять текстом и по нажатию ПКМ менять местами парные и непарные столбцы

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Задание полностью в оригинале:

> Заповнити 0-у сторінку відеопам’яті довільним текстом. При натисканні
>   на праву кнопку мишки вміст парних та непарних стовпців екрану
>   міняються місцями.
>
> (Заполнить 0-ю страницу видеопамяти произвольным текстом. При нажатии
>   на правую кнопку мышки содержимое парных и непарных столбцов экрана
>   меняются местами.)

**Что сделал:**

1. реагирует на ПКМ, по нажатию выводит строку на экран

**В чем нужна помощь:**

1. Заполнить текстом 0-ю страницу( думаю если вначале написать

   ```
   mov    ah,09h
   mov    dx, offset msg
   int    21h
   ```

   то будет ОК, поправьте если ошибаюсь )
2. Менять местами столбцы. Нету идей как это сделать. Как я понимаю должно быть что то типа ABCD -> BADC

   ```
   assume cs:code,ds:data
   data segment
   msg db '-=* Hello World *=-$'
   data ends

   code segment
   begin:  
       mov ax, data                                            ;Получаем адрес данных
       mov ds,ax
       mov es,ax


       mov ah, 00h ; задаем
       mov al,10h  ; графический
       int 10h ; режим

       xor ax,ax                                               ;помещаем в ax ноль
       int 33h                                                 ;Инициализируем мышь

       mov     cx,11111b                                       ;Обработчик будет ловить все события мыши(все единицы)
       mov     ax,0ch                                          ;
       push    cs                                              ;перемещаем cs в es
       pop     es                                              ;
       mov     dx,offset mouse_proc                            ;указываем имя функции - обработчика мышки
       int     33h                                             ;Вызываем прерывание чтобы это все применить

       mov     ah, 0                                           ;Ожиданем нажатия любой клавиши
       int     16h                                             ;
       mov     ax, 000Ch                                       ;Если нажали клавишу ( не мышь ), то:
       mov     cx, 0000h                                       ;Удаляем обработчик событий мыши
       int     33h                                             ;
       mov ax,4c00h                                            ;
       int 21h                                                 ;Выходим из программы


   mouse_proc proc                                             ;Функция - обработчик событий мыши
       mov     ax, 0003h                                       ;
       int     33h                                             ;Получаем информацию о мышке

       test    bx, 00000010b                                   ;Проверяем, если нажата Правая Кнопка Мыши, то на метку L2
       jnz     L1                                              ;

   retf                                                        ;Иначе, выход из функции                                               

       L1:                 
       mov    ah,09h
       ;lea    dx, msg
       ;int    21h

       mov    ah,09h
       mov    dx, offset msg
       int    21h

       retf                                                    ;Выход из функции

   mouse_proc endp  

   code ends 
   end begin
   ```

Comment: Первый же вопрос: зачем вам графический режим? Второй: выводить в графическом режиме функцией DOS - э... Вообще, сильно подозреваю, что в задании речь идёт о текстовом режиме и о прямой работе с видеопамятью в нём, где содержимое каждой страницы можно представить массивом байт. Тогда обмен столбцов - тривиальная задача.

Comment: да. Скорее всего Вы правы. Нужно вывести текст в текстовом режиме видеопамяти и потом поменять местами парные и не парные колонки. У Вас есть идеи как это сделать ?

Comment: Сейчас у меня получилось вывести алфавит вот так: 


`mov ax, 0b800h <br> 
mov es, ax 
mov cx, 26 
mov si, 0 

mov bl, 'a' 

l: 
mov al, bl 
mov ah, 00111100b  
mov es:[si],ax 
add si, 2 
inc bl 
loop l`
Это прямая запись в видеопамять ?
не могу понять как менять местами.

Comment: 1) установите текстовый режим NxM (например, 80x25) 2) заполните массив размером (N*2)*M парами символ/атрибут 3) залейте его на первую страницу видеопамити (0B800h:0) 4) поменяйте местами в этом массиве пары вертикальных столбцов 5) пункт 3.

Comment: Боюсь это сложно будет для меня. Сейчас у меня выводиться вот так 
`mov bl, 'a'

l: 
mov al, bl 
mov ah, 00111100b 
mov es:[si],ax 
add si, 2 
inc bl
loop l`
с таким выводом можно придумать какую-то замену колонок ?

Comment: P.S. немогу заставить его выводить код с новой строки ...

Comment: Для начала почитайте про организацию видеопамяти в текстовом режиме. Никакой "вывода новой строки" там не нужно. Я не знаю чем тут ещё помочь, что *нужно* сделать - написал, хотите пойти каким-то другим путём - идите :) А массив выводится *весь сразу*, одной командой.

Comment: Спаибо за помощь